# Draw n-sided regular polygon with center point, radius and coords of one vertex

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Not sure if this should be posted as a programming question or a math question but I need to draw an n-sided regular polygon providing center, radius, and end coords of one edge.

Here is my code so far, but it is only able to draw the polygon with the right most edge of the polygon vertical:

```
from tkinter import *
import math

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.w = Canvas(width=800, height=600, bg='black')
        self.w.draw_regular_polygon((400,400), 100, 3, outline='green')
        self.w.grid(row=0, column=0)
    def _draw_regular_polygon(self, center, radius, n, **kwargs):
        coord_list = []
        for i in range(n):
            coord_x = center[0] + radius * math.cos((math.pi/n) * (1 + 2 * i))
            coord_y = center[1] + radius * math.sin((math.pi/n) * (1 + 2 * i))
            coord_list.append(coord_x)
            coord_list.append(coord_y)
        return self.create_polygon(coord_list, **kwargs)
    Canvas.draw_regular_polygon = _draw_regular_polygon
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I need to be able either provide the end points of the vertical line or be able to spin the polygon so that each point in oriented in a specified direction.

My end goal with this project is to draw an lattice of n-sided regular polygons. I am using tkinter because it is the package I am most familiar with but I would be willing to learn a different one if there is one that can handle it better, but not a package that will draw the lattice for me. I would like to be able to understand the composition of the lattice rather than just have it drawn for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional rotation angle to your function; add that constant value to the rotation around the circle that creates the coordinate list.

I've slightly re-ordered your coordinate system, and added a fix value so the *bottom* line is always drawn straight at an angle of `0`. To rotate to a next half-interval between two points, add `math.pi/n` as an angle.

```
from tkinter import *
import math

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.w = Canvas(width=800, height=600, bg='black')
        self.w.draw_regular_polygon((400,400), 100, 5, 0, outline='green')
        self.w.draw_regular_polygon((400,400), 100, 5, math.pi/5, outline='red')
        self.w.grid(row=0, column=0)
    def _draw_regular_polygon(self, center, radius, n, angle, **kwargs):
        angle -= (math.pi/n)
        coord_list = [[center[0] + radius * math.sin((2*math.pi/n) * i - angle),
            center[1] + radius * math.cos((2*math.pi/n) * i - angle)] for i in range(n)]
        return self.create_polygon(coord_list, **kwargs)
    Canvas.draw_regular_polygon = _draw_regular_polygon
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: Un-rotated and rotated pentagons]

(That said: the only repeating n-side polygon lattices are for `n = [3,4,6]` where the only problematic one is `3`, which you could have hard-coded.)